# How do I change all my values within a df column using a loop / lambda function (the simplest way of doing so)

Tags: python, database, loops, analysis

```
sweets = pd.DataFrame({Name: Sweet_count: Rank, "John" : 12: 1, "Mike": 4: 2, "James": 17: 3, "Michael" : 6: 4, "Sam": 19: 5, "Jack": 15: 6})
```

We have here a table of names, number of sweets each person has, and a hierarchy of who has the most/least amount. The values in place for the hierarchy are wrong and I need to update them in order from top to bottom.

```
sweets.sort_values("Sweet_count", inplace = True)
```

I now need to have the correct rank assigned to each of these values. Sam has the most sweet, therefore he needs have position 1 and Mike has the least amount position 6.

So how would I write a loop allowing me to iterate through the column of incorrect values and have them ordered the correct way?

NOTE: in my real dataset I cant do this job manually as there are too many values.

The desired result here would be:

```
sweets = pd.DataFrame({Name: Sweet_count: Rank, "John" : 12: 4, "Mike": 4: 6, "James": 17: 2, "Michael" : 6: 5, "Sam": 19: 1, "Jack": 15: 3})
```

Comment: Your dictionary is not valid python.

Comment: @ggorlen thanks! I have added it to the end

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to use a loop/lambda, or can it use pandas' inbuilt rank function, like so:

```
sweets["Correct_Rank"] = sweets["Sweet_count"].rank(ascending=False)
```

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html